# understanding decomposition of a measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In reference to this question [Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12871/lebesgue-decomposition-theorem?rq=1) and in general I would like to ask why does one care about the decomposition of a measure? What it helps in any way with respect to probability theory or whatever. Is there a straight forward technique by which one decomposes a measure in three-part as mentioned in the answer of the above question?   A nice reference reading would be grand or otherwise. Thanks so much!

Comment: The Lebesgue Decomposition theorem is used to [decompose the spectrum of a linear operator][1],and it is used in the [Levy-Ito Decomposition][2].



  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_of_spectrum_(functional_analysis)
[2]:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_process#Lévy–Itô_

Comment: ah! long wiki read! waiting for some Philosophical answer Thanks anyway! I will read them!